# Proving these are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

We have the following equality (in physics) $$c^2t^2-x^2 = c^2t'^2-x'^2$$

where:

$t' =  \gamma (t- \dfrac{vx}{c^2})$

$x' = \gamma(x-vt)$

$\gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

My textbook gives no proof of this, and I thought it would be a nice algebraic exercise to perform, but I have failed to find it. I get stuck at the following expression:

$$c^2t'^2-x'^2 = \gamma ^2 (c^2t^2 + \dfrac{v^2x^2}{c^2} - x^2 - v^2t^2)$$

This very slightly resembles $c^2t^2-x^2$, but I still can't figure out how to get to that expression. Can anybody help?

Comment: Hey so before you do anymore work you made an error when substituting for $t'^2$ and $x'^2$. What you have is $(a - b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ but what it should be is $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$

Comment: @Gage I didn't do that, the two other terms cancel each other out, at least, that's what I found.

Comment: Oh I totally didn't even check for that my bad. Have you plugged in the definition for $\gamma$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  c^2t'^2 - x'^2
      &= c^2\gamma^2\left(t - \frac{v x}{c^2}\right)^2 - \gamma^2(x-vt)^2 \\
      &= \frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}\left(c^2t^2 - 2tvx + \frac{v^2x^2}{c^2} - x^2 + 2xvt - v^2t^2\right) \\
      &= \frac{c^2}{c^2-v^2}\left(c^2t^2 + \frac{v^2x^2}{c^2} - x^2 - v^2t^2\right) \\
      &= \frac{c^2}{c^2-v^2}(c^2-v^2)t^2 + \frac{c^2}{c^2-v^2}\left(\frac{v^2x^2}{c^2} - x^2\right) \\
      &= c^2t^2 + \frac{c^2}{c^2-v^2}\cdot\frac{(v^2-c^2)x^2}{c^2} \\
      &= c^2t^2 - x^2.
\end{align*}